# How can I change the Memgraph port when using Docker?

Tags: memgraphdb

When I run the Memgrpah platform, a MEmgraph runs on port 7687. I already use that port by another container. How can I change the Memgraph port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Memgraph configuration is available in Docker's named volume mg_etc. On Linux systems, it should be in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/mg_etc/_data/memgraph.conf`. Keep in mind that this way of specifying configuration options is only valid if Memgraph was started using volumes.

When using Docker, you can also specify the configuration options in the `docker run` command:

```
docker run -p 7687:7687 memgraph/memgraph --log-level=TRACE
```